# Adding directory to my path through ~/.bash_profile in bash?

Tags: shell, path, bash

I want to add a directory to my PATH through the ~/.bash_profile file, though I don't have a file like this in my Ubuntu. I have the following code, which will check whether people have that file or not, and if not will create one and add all the existing path directories and the one entered by the user.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please enter a directory that you want to add to your PATH: "
read dr

if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]
then
    # Add the read 'dr' directory to the end of the line that starts 
    # with PATH=, in your ~/.bash_profile file
    source ~/.bash_profile
else
    echo "PATH=$PATH:$dr" > ~/.bash_profile
    echo "export PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
    source ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

The point is that, if the file already exists, I don't know how can I check to find the line that starts with PATH=, and then add the directory entered by the user to the end of that line. Please note that this is just an exercise given to me. I should add a directory entered by the user to the PATH through ~/.bash_profile. Though, I don't know why someone should bother to use ~/.bash_profile to add new directory to the PATH.

Comment: `.bash_profile` is ideal for making changes to the login environment, as the file is executed only once, and any variables marked for export will be available in every child shell without needing to set them in `.bashrc`.

Comment: Also, it would be good practice if this variable is already set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the lines you are adding to a new `.bash_profile`:

```
echo "PATH=$PATH:$dr" > ~/.bash_profile
echo "export PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

The first one already adds `$dr` to the `PATH`, regardless of what is already in `PATH`. This means you can do the same thing even if `.bash_profile` already exists: just tack on a new line that appends yet another directory:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
echo "export PATH=\$PATH:$dr" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

A few things to note:

1. Ensure that `.bash_profile` exists by `touch`ing it; then you don't need to test for its existence.
2. Only one line is needed; you can set a variable when you use `export` to mark it for export to the environment.
3. Escape the `$` in `$PATH` so that a literal dollar sign is written to `.bash_profile`; the same is not needed for `$dr` because you want to let that expand so the proper directory is added.
4. Append this new line using `>>`, so you don't overwrite the existing file.

Answer (score -2):

```
~/.bashrc
```

Try this file in home.

Comment: As I said I have an exercise and I need to use ~/.bash_profile, and bash scripting.