# Add an entire directory with subdirectories to path

Tags: python, bash, path

How can I add an entire directory with subdirectories to my path? I need it to get at least 2 deep from my python directory. `python/x/y/MYEXE` and `python/x/MYEXE`. Thanks! I know how to add it, I just need all the paths.

```
python
├── artist
│   ├── curses
│   └── draw
├── binary
├── check
│   ├── pycheck.py
│   └── README.md
├── classexample
│   └── myclass
├── clixr
│   ├── clix
│   └── crcards.json
├── conn4generator
├── conway
│   ├── cell_checker_lib.py
│   └── game
├── elementify
│   ├── elementify
│   └── elements.txt
├── encryption
│   ├── encoder1
│   │   ├── decode
│   │   └── encode
│   └── encoder2
│       ├── code
│       └── decode
```

Comment: You just add it twice. Answered many times before.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508892/adding-directory-to-my-path-through-bash-profile-in-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them like that :

`PATH=$PATH$( find $HOME/scripts/ -type d -printf ":%p" )`

See this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17718/230876)

But as mention in the linked page, it is not recommended as for the security risks involved.

Comment: why not use  `find $HOME/python -type d -maxdepth 2 -not -path ".git/*"`

Comment: Because you didn't ask to ignore directories neither to limit to 2 depth, but to add ***at least*** 2 depth

Answer (score 0):

`PATH=$PATH$( find $HOME/python/ -maxdepth 2 -type d -not -path "/.git/*" -printf ":%p" )`

- `type d` = directory
- `maxdepth 2` = only go down 2 directories
- `not path ".git/*"` = excludes .git stuff
- `printf ":%p"` = turns it into `path:path1` format

Thanks to @Esteban for the `printf` flag